# How to control a flag in two different procedural blocks in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I want to rise a flag once I enter procedural block#1, and I want to reset it to zero in another procedural block. Of course I get an error saying the flag is driven by too many drivers. How can I overcome this problem?

Block 1, sensitive to sw (FPGA board switches):

```
always @ (sw)
flag =1;
begin 
case (sw)   
8'bxxxxxx01: x2= 13'd1249;
8'bxxxxxx10: x2= 13'd2499;
8'bxxxxxx11: x2= 13'd3749;

endcase

end
```

Block 2, sensitive to CLK:

```
always @ (posedge CLK)

        begin

        if (counter2 == x2)
        begin
        counter2 <=0;
        flag=0;
        end

        else
        counter2 <= counter2 +1;

        end
```

Assuming all initialization are taken care of.

Comment: NB: if you have do not cares in your case statement you should use `casez`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to have set and reset flags and a FSM which listens to these flags.

```
localparam S_RESET = 2'b0;
localparam S_SET   = 1'b1;
reg state;

always @(posedge clk) begin
  case ({flag_set, flag_reset})
    2'b00 : state <= state;
    2'b01 : state <= S_RESET;
    2'b10 : state <= S_SET;
    2'b11 : state <= S_SET; //Choose priority
  endcase
end
```

But to note that `always @ (sw)` should be written as `always @(*)` ie with an automatic sensitivity list. This represents a combinatorial block of hardware, all outputs should be based on inputs (or flipflops).

I hope this makes it clear that:

```
always @ (sw)
  flag =1;
```

does not represent hardware and will not be synthesisable. `flag` is based on triggering the simulator not a value based on an input.